# Is there a logic gate (NAND, OR, etc.) which forms a group under the set $\{0,1\}?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, boolean-algebra

Many of the binary logic operators satisfy algebraic properties like associativity, closure, and having an inverse. I was wondering if you could form a group, or any other algebraic structure using one (or more) of these gates.

Comment: You might also be interested in the [functional completeness of operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact you can form *every* algebraic structure the set $2 = \{ 0, 1 \}$ possesses using compositions of logic gates. This is because, by [functional completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness), the standard logic gates can express every Boolean function $2^n \to 2$.

So it's natural to ask: what is the structure on $2$ given by all of the Boolean functions together? This is the "maximally general algebraic structure" that $2$ can possess. The answer is that it is equivalent to the structure of a **[Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure))** (using AND, OR, and NOT) or equivalently a **[Boolean ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring)** (using XOR, NOT, and AND). Specializations of this structure include

- the structure of a [lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)) (using AND and OR)
- the structure of an idempotent commutative [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) (using either AND or OR)
- the structure of an [abelian group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group), or more precisely a vector space over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_2$ (using XOR).

There are other more exotic specializations given by [Post's lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_lattice).

Another interesting question is: what algebraic structure do the logic gates *themselves* form? The answer is that they form what is called a **[Lawvere theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawvere_theory)**; see [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/11/26/the-lawvere-theory-of-boolean-functions/) for some details.

Answer (score 7):

Actually the set $\{0,1\}$ with AND, OR and NOT is an example (and the most basic nontrivial one) of a [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)). Its associated Boolean ring $(\{0,1\}, XOR, AND)$ is isomorphic in this case to $(\mathbb Z_2, +_2, \cdot_2)$.

Answer (score 4):

The XOR gate corresponds to addition modulo 2, thus it forms a group.