# What is the most general algebraic structure that a finite set has?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, universal-algebra

For an object $X$ in a category with finite products, define its **endomorphism Lawvere theory** to be the [Lawvere theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere+theory) generated by $X$: its $n$-ary operations are given by $\text{Hom}(X^n, X)$, and so accordingly it describes the most general algebraic structure that $X$ possesses. Some quick examples:

1. The endomorphism Lawvere theory of the abelian group $\mathbb{Z}$ is the Lawvere theory of abelian groups. (This is specific to abelian groups.)
2. The endomorphism Lawvere theory of the set $2 = \{ 0, 1 \}$ is the Lawvere theory of Boolean algebras, or equivalently Boolean rings. This recently came up [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2599027/is-there-a-logic-gate-nand-or-etc-which-forms-a-group-under-the-set-0-1/2600160#2600160).
3. The endomorphism Lawvere theory of [Sierpinski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space) is, I believe, the Lawvere theory of (bounded) distributive lattices, although I haven't checked this.
4. As an interesting generalization of the second example, the endomorphism Lawvere theory of the set $3 = \{ 0, 1, 2 \}$ is the Lawvere theory of a ternary generalization of Boolean rings: $\mathbb{F}_3$-algebras such that every element $x$ satisfies $x^3 = x$. This follows from the fact that every ternary function $3^n \to 3$ can be represented as a polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_3$ which is unique if we require that the degree of the polynomial in each variable is at most $2$, or equivalently if we impose the relation $x^3 = x$ on each variable.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to continue this pattern: that is,

> What is the endomorphism Lawvere theory of the finite set $4 = \{ 0, 1, 2, 3 \}$? Of any finite set?

(An answer should be a description in terms of generators and relations - some operations that generate all the others under composition and product, and the axioms they satisfy - which is ideally related to familiar algebraic structures such as rings.)

I am only confident I know the answer for a finite set of prime size $p$, which again generalizes the Boolean case: it should be $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebras such that every element satisfies $x^p = x$.

Comment: It seems your description using $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebras works when $p$ is a prime power, not just a prime.

Comment: Hmm, looks like you're right; we're really just using properties of finite fields. Okay, cool. So now the smallest set I don't know the answer for is $6$.

Comment: And for sets whose cardinality is not a prime power, you can't just use the ring operations for any ring structure, since the ring splits as a direct product by the Chinese remainder theorem and all polynomials will respect this splitting (for instance, the image of any polynomial must be a "rectangle" for the splitting).

Comment: Just to make sure I follow correctly: Are these algebras unital?

Comment: @MatheinBoulomenos: yes. Otherwise we would not be able to express constant functions.

Comment: If $A$ is a finite commutative ring, then the $A$-algebra structure on $A$ together with the characteristic function of $\{0\}$ will generate the endomorphism Lawvere theory of the set $A$.  Describing the relations seems tricky though.

Comment: I think Todd Trimble's answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69086/lawvere-theories-versus-classical-universal-algebra) is relevant.

Comment: To be more clear, I think you are just looking for a primal algebra of order $n$, and the $n$-valued Post algebra is an example of this.

Comment: @Eran: thanks. Apparently a primal algebra is an algebra $A$ such that every function $A^n \to A$ is a term. I want something stronger than this, namely I want every function to be a *unique* term. Todd's answer is definitely relevant, and it looks like there's a reasonably nice description by generators and relations in it.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan : why a unique term ? Since you're looking at the Lawvere theory, essentially you're interested in the clone, and for that the specific presentation doesn't matter (that's one of the points of Lawvere theories)

Comment: @Max: maybe I've misunderstood the definition of a primal algebra, or maybe we are using the word "unique" differently. I took the definition to mean the following, in Lawvere theory terms: a primal algebra is a pair consisting of a Lawvere theory and a model $A$ of that Lawvere theory such that the map from $n$-ary operations in the Lawvere theory to functions $A^n \to A$ is surjective. I want the Lawvere theory to be exactly the endomorphism Lawvere theory of $A$, which means I want this map to be bijective, not surjective. Consider explicitly $A = 2$; I want the Lawvere...

Comment: theory to be Boolean rings and not, say, $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebras, which would satisfy surjectivity but not bijectivity.

Comment: Oh ! Ok I think I get it; I misunderstood you because I thought you meant "terms" in the syntactic sense, which didn't make much sense in this setting

Comment: Yes, I meant terms up to equivalence (I don't know if this is the right word; I mean I consider two terms the same if they define the same function on all models, or equivalently if the axioms prove they are equal). Have I correctly understood the definition of a primal algebra then?